# Add button to Drupal ckeditor

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I'm just learning Drupal and would like to add a button to the CKEditor. I've tried a few techniques and I'm never able to get a new button to appear. Here's the module I have so far.

Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work?

---

Here's a list of other files besides the ones included:

- image.png (/sites/all/modules/excel_to_html/images/image.png) - icon
- excel_to_html.info (/sites/all/modules/excel_to_html/excel_to_html.info)

### excel_to_html.module

location : /sites/all/modules/excel_to_html/excel_to_html.module

```
<?php
function excel_to_html_ckeditor_plugin() {
  return array(
        'plugin_name' => array(
            'name' => 'excel_to_html',
            'desc' => t('Plugin description'),
            'path' =>  drupal_get_path('module', 'excel_to_html')  .'/plugins/excel_to_html/',
            'buttons' => array(
                array('label' => 'Button label', 'icon' => '/images/image.png'),
            )
        )
    );
}
```

### plugin.js

location : /sites/all/modules/excel_to_html/plugins/excel_to_html/plugin.js

```
(function() {
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('excel_to_html', 
  {
        icons: 'images/image.png',

        init: function(editor) 
        {
          editor.addCommand('excel_convert', 
          {
              exec : function(editor) 
              {
                alert('testing button!');
                //var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
              }
          });
          editor.ui.addButton('excel_to_html', 
          {
            label: 'Convert Excel to table',
            command: 'excel_convert',
            icon: this.path + 'images/image.png'
          });
        },
        afterInit: function (editor) 
        {
            alert('done');
        }
  });
})();
```

Comment: First things first, do you have drush, have you been ensuring to clear cache.

Comment: I have been clearing cache but do not h ave drush.